# Azure Data Lake Store "The access token is not provided in the 'Authorization' header" using HttpClient

Tags: c#, azure, azure-active-directory, azure-data-lake

I'm having issues trying to access Azure Data Lake Store via the WebHDFS APIs using an HttpClient in .NET

This is my code:

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    HttpRequestMessage message = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Put, resourceUri);

    message.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", _accessToken);
    message.Content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(body));
    message.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");

    var result = await client.SendAsync(message);
    var content = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

    result.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
}
```

Which returns me a 401 with this message: `"The access token is not provided in the 'Authorization' header"`

The weird thing is if I take the exact accessToken and resourceUri and put it in Postman it works fine (201).

I've added the application under Access control, and in the Data Explorer > Access tab, and have given full rights (Read, Write, Execute).

I even rewrote this using RestSharp yet the same error is given to me, I checked the JWT token it is definitely correct and returning data when I use it in Postman. It seems like the header is being stripped out somewhere.

This is driving me crazy, I can't figure out what I am doing wrong! Can anyone please help?

Comment: Do you see the Authorization header being sent with the request if you inspect traffic using a tool like Fiddler?  If it is being stripped out or otherwise modified, it should be shown there.  If that doesn't help, then you should compare the request your code generates with the successful one generated through Postman, to see where the difference lies.  Could you edit your question to mention whether you've tried these out and what the outcome was?

Comment: @MattH Just checked with fiddler, I see two requests a 307 (temp redirect) which has the Authorization header, and a 401 which doesn't! Seems like the redirect is whats causing the header to get lost.

Comment: Ah I've solved it! The redirected URI has an extra parameter *&write=true* - I just updated the URL to include and it seems like its working fine now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue seems to be related to a redirect that was happening that added an extra parameter added to the operation in the resource URI.

The parameter was "write=true". So I've updated the Resource URI to include the parameter.

i.e. for PUT operation "https://yourstore.azuredatalakestore.net/webhdfs/v1/xxx?op=CREATE&write=true"

Very weird behaviour but it works now.